# How to scan MAC address of other devices in a local network in Android?

Tags: java, android, ip, wifi, mac-address

Is there a clear way and can be implemented easily to scan the local network to get MAC address of the devices connected to my WiFi network in android?Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that Android will allow you access to raw sockets in order to send ARP requests, so probably the easiest way is to sand some traffic (this can be any kind of traffic) to all IP addresses in the network forcing the phone to get the  MAC addresses for all IPs via ARP. Then you can read the ARP cache (`/proc/net/arp`) and get the IP to MAC mappings.